# Loop in Firebase Recycler Adapter

Tags: android, firebase, for-loop, android-recyclerview, firebaseui

I'm getting the list of user ids from database. And its getting the values correctly. I'm using `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` and when I iterate that list in `onBindViewHolder` the loops runs as the size of list. For example over here  :

```
 adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Profiles, DonarViewHolder>(model) {
            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull DonarViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull Profiles profiles) {
               for (int i = 0 ; i<list.size() ; i++){
                  Toast.makeText(List.this,"List :" +list.get(i), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               }
            }
 }
```

Over here I have 5 item in list and while iterating I'm toasting each item . So in here the loop run for 25 time, its shows each item 5 time in sequence. First it shows 5 items orderly after showing last item it start toasting from first one again and continues till 5 time as the size of list.
So how do I cater this and make it only iterate the whole items for once only?

Comment: I think you should not iterate over list.size. Rather, you can get the data directly using the position as an index. Try this `list.get(position)`. Also, please post the data in the list as a reference.

Comment: if I do list.get(position) then it will toast first item five time then second item and goes on
Eventually it doing the samething

Comment: No No No! You have to remove the loop altogether and simply write the `Toast` line

Comment: yup that worked man literally I was fighting with this for 2 days
Can you please elaborate a little why this issue occur if we apply a loop?

Comment: Please check my answer to better understand your issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`onBindViewHolder` is called by `RecyvlerView` to display the data at the specified position. Since you have all the data in a `List`, their corresponding index will be the same as the position of the `itemView`.

In your function, you are iterating over all the items in the `list` for each `itemView` which the `ViewHolder` is generating.

You have to remove the `for` loop from your code and simply use the `position` as the `index` to retrieve data from your `list`, whose `index` is same as `position`.

Try this code:

```
adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Profiles, DonarViewHolder>(model) {
            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull DonarViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull Profiles profiles) {

                  Toast.makeText(List.this,"List :" +list.get(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
 }
```

For this method, every time an `itemView` is generated, it will be at a `position` and with this as an index, you can easily get the data from the `list`.

For your scenario, since you are already inside each `itemView` being generated inside the `onBindViewHolder`, and then you are iterating for each element in your `list`, hence every item is being displayed exactly the same number of times, as the size of the `list`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing a method that you can use to call each item individually. 
create a setter and getter for your item. In your loop you can then call it list.get(position).getItem .

Comment: You can simply do it by list.get(position) then why make an extra method

Comment: I mean you need to create a setter and getter class for your recycle adapter. So when you are trying to retrieve a certain data you can call it individually.